# Using append with a dict

Tags: python, unicode, dictionary, append

I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I am pulling cell values from Excel--Ones for category, subitem and requirements.

If the category and subitem already exists in the dict

```
ldict
```

I want to append it.  I am currently doing it like so:

```
ldict[(cat, sub)].append(req)
```

where cat, sub, and req are unicode values from Excel converted to strings:

```
req = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', sh.Cells(a,i).Value).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jenhuang\My Documents\dude\comparestrings.py", line 35, in <module>
ldict[(cat, sub)].append(req)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

My overall goal is to search these requirement strings within a certain category and subcategory for common words.  This is to see if I can create an automated process where I can suggest categories and subcategories for requirement strings.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I assume it's because my interpreter is calling

```
ldict[(cat,sub)]
```

as a string.  I'm looking for a solution to this.

Comment: What's in the `cat`, `sub`, `req`, and `ldict[(cat, sub)]`, and what do you want to end up in `ldict[(cat, sub)]` after this line? Without knowing what you're trying to do, we can't tell you how to do it, or what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @abarnert I've edited it.  Please take a look now.

Comment: I still don't see what's in `ldict[(cat, sub)]`, or what you want to end up there after this line. Is it supposed to be a string holding a word? A list holding a bunch of such strings? A dict mapping sets of words to some other type? A sorted dict mapping sockets to stack frames using the peer IP address as the key?

Comment: @abarnert ldict[(cat, sub)] is a dict of tuples holding a bunch of strings.

Comment: That's not possible. If the values are tuples of strings, the error message would be `'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'`. So, you obviously don't have what you think you have, and you're not going to be able to fix it until you figure out what you have. Try printing out those values and their types to see where you've gotten confused. At any rate, if you _did_ have tuples of strings, you can't append to a tuple—but you can just do `ldict[(cat, sub)] = ldict[(cat, sub)] + (req,)`, which is probably good enough.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unclear with my message.  The tuples are the keys, and the list of strings are the values.  The tuples represent the category and subitem.  The goal afterwards is to figure out what common words are between the strings in the list of values and assign the number of times the word appears and the word itself to a dictionary ie dict[(category, subitem)] = (word, number of time the word appears in the list of strings)

Comment: I am trying to format all strings found in a specific category and specific subitem as a list of strings, and find the commonalities between the all the strings.  I realize that I have trouble articulating, I am sorry.

Comment: I appreciate all your advice and help so far.  It's been very instructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append() is a list method.  The dict has a string there.  If you want to append items to a list, you need to build your dictionary to contain lists.  I would suggest something like `ldict.setdefault(key, []).append(whatever)` whenever putting values into this dictionary to ensure you always have a list.

Comment: Great answer!  
I was also thinking about setting the key--tuple(category, subcategory)--to the first string as a list with only one string in it.

IE

     ldict[(cat, subcat)] = [req]
and then

    ldict[(cat,sub)].append(req) for future strings found.  
Would this work?

Comment: @Doof12 Sure it'd work but then you'd have to have a special case to detect if it's the first item.  Using setdefault() that behavior is built in.  What makes the most sense depends on the flow of your program.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're trying to do is this:

```
ldict[(cat, sub)] = req
```

Just like Sean suggested: if you're trying to access the list with the key `(cat, sub)` in `ldict` and then append `req` to it, use `setdefault()`:

```
ldict.setdefault((cat, sub), []).append(req)
```

This one sets the value of `(cat, sub)` to an empty list if not set before, otherwise it returns the list and finally appends `req` to it.

**And since this obviously is the answer, do Sean a favour and accept his answer…**

Comment: I'm actually trying to append a new value to an existing list of values.

Comment: To **what** list and **which** values? If you do `ldict[(cat, sub)].append(req)`, you try to append `req` to a (yet not described) value with the key `(cat, sub)` in the dict `edict`. I don't understand why Sean's answer does not solve your problem…